# Excel formula to find val in column and add to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel to find a certain value in column C (the number 280) and if it finds that value in column C I want it to add a different value in column J ($ 35.00)

Is there an automated way or a way to do this with a formula?

I have tried sorting by column 2 then adding to column J but I can never get the spreadsheet to go back to the original way it was.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple (put this in column J) :

```
=IF(C1=280; "35.00";"")
```

If it won´t work, you have a different language in excel.